# Flatpak runtime OS system components update - not completing

Tags: updates, system

For some reason EOS is desperately trying (and failing to update)

[image]

I don't think I have and definitely don't use nvidia-470-74

It's not a serious problem, but a nuisance.

How do I, please, get rid of it? and stop EOS telling me that I should update something that I don't need?

**EDIT:** interweb search seems to bring some issues

(although no solution...) related to `"Flatpak runtime"`  ????

**another EDIT:** found what looks like related issue? apparently closed?

https://github.com/elementary/appcenter/issues/1529

**one more EDIT**

```
~$ flatpak update
        
Looking for updates…
        
Info: org.kde.Platform//5.15 is end-of-life, with reason:
We strongly recommend moving to the latest stable version of the Plaform and SDK
        
                ID                                                    Branch            Op            Remote             Download
         1. [\] org.freedesktop.Platform.GL.nvidia-470-74             1.4               u             flathub            1.0 kB / 271.3 MB
         2. [ ] org.kde.Platform.Locale                               5.15              r
         3. [ ] org.kde.Platform                                      5.15              r

Warning: While downloading https://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/470.74/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-470.74.run: Could not connect: Socket I/O timed out

Changes complete.
```

**yet another EDIT...**

this time tried:

```
~$ flatpak uninstall org.freedesktop.Platform.GL.nvidia-470-74


        ID                                                  Branch           Op
 1. [-] org.freedesktop.Platform.GL.nvidia-470-74           1.4              r

Uninstall complete.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that my last attempt has solved the issue.

I am posting just in case it helps anybody else searching for a solution to similar problem:

```
~$ flatpak uninstall org.freedesktop.Platform.GL.nvidia-470-74

        ID                                                  Branch           Op
 1. [-] org.freedesktop.Platform.GL.nvidia-470-74           1.4              r

Uninstall complete.
```